# Why does UITableViewCell and UITableViewHeaderFooterView does not share some common ancestor?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uitableview

Besides `UIView` itself.

I mean they both have contentView properties and so many similarities. What does apple think when they decided that the common parent between `UItableViewCell` and `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` is `UIView` instead of something more common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's mostly for historical reasons: `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` was introduced in iOS 6. At this point `UITableViewCell` existed since 6 major iOS versions. Before iOS 6 you've use plain UIViews for headers and footers.

When Apple decided that the reuse concept is beneficial for supplementary views, too, they could not pull this part of the API out into a new class and insert it in between `UITableViewCell` and `UIView`. Also, Objective-C does not tend to introduce so many classes for each tiny implementation detail as, for example, java.

Comment: Makes way more sense to put all headers in an array and recall that then. There aren't that many headers anyway.

Comment: The problem with reusing headers is that there's no way of knowing when the table view has finished with a header. Observing the view hierarchy might not be enough.

Comment: That's fine. The headers will stay in memory. It's not a lot anyway.